# Google Sheets: Apply StikeThrough when ANY value entered into column

Tags: google-sheets, strikethrough

I am making a sign-up sheet with available dates on the top, and names on the side.  When a person puts their initials in one of the date columns, I'd like the date on top to change to StrikeThrough so that it is easily identified to others as being no longer available for selection.   Any ideas on how to do this?  So it needs to be something like: If ANY text appears anywhere in column E, Then E1:E3 changes to StrikeThrough....  Thanks!

I am using Google Sheets, PC, Windows 8. I am new here and if won't let me post images... Here is an idea of what I'm working with: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41966437/OVERTIME%20SIGN%20UP%20%20%20Google%20Sheets.png

See my answers to the question below for more details.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, how many datecolumns do you have ? Dates are on what row ? Text will be entered one row below that ? In your question I see E1:E3 which is part of a column, shoudn't that be a row instead ?

Comment: Hello, The dates range from column E, Row 1 and extend to column AR, Row 1, but each month there are more or less dates.  Dates will always begin in column E, Row 1 (E1) and span that row.

Comment: So a date in cell E1 will have a persons initials entered into one cell of that column, which spans from E4:E25.  This may change if we add or a lose a person eligible for sign up.

Comment: Here is a link to a screegrab that may help explain.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41966437/OVERTIME%20SIGN%20UP%20%20%20Google%20Sheets.png

Comment: In that screengrab, I have manually added the strikethrough... I want that to happen automatically when initials are entered as show.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if this works ? As a bonus I also made the line-though dissappear if the intitials are erased (and no other initials are in the same column).

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if (e.range.columnStart < 5 || e.range.rowStart < 3) return;
e.range.offset(-e.range.rowStart + 1, 0)
    .setFontLine(e.value ? "line-through" : "normal");
```

}

Note: the script will work on every sheet of the spreadsheet(workbook) if you need it to work on 1 sheet only, fill in the sheet name in the code below and use this instead of the previous:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if (ss.getName() !== 'Sheet1' || e.range.columnStart < 5 || e.range.rowStart < 3) return;
e.range.offset(-e.range.rowStart + 1, 0)
    .setFontLine(e.value ? "line-through" : "normal");
```

}

Comment: Also note: the script uses an event object. So don't try to run it from the script editor (or you will get e = undefined). Instead try doing some edits and see if the strike-through happens.

Comment: Thank your for the assistance.  I am unfamiliar with scripts, and therefore I don't know how or where to enter this in my sheet.  Do I open the 'Script Editor' and past it there?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Copy and paste it in the script editor and save it. You will be prompted to give the project a name. Do so and you should be all set up. As mentioned above, try the script by doing some edits in the spreadsheet.

Comment: I opened the spreadsheet, click Tools > Script Editor, and then replaced the content in that box with your script above, however it won't work.  I named the script, but upon attempting to save I am getting errors.  Take a look at this screen grab: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41966437/StikeThrough.png

Comment: When I first open the script editor there are a few items already in there: function myFunction() {
  
}

Comment: Do I replace that with your script, or do I paste your script before/after/inside any of that?